# can I use nginx ingress controller oauth2_proxy in kubernetes with azure active directory without cookies

Tags: nginx, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I am in the process of changing from an Azure webservice to azure kubernetes to host an api. I have the solution working with nginx and oauth2_proxy and azure active directory. However the solution requires a cookie to function. 
As this is an api and the external security will be managed by an AWS API Gateway with a custom authoriser. I would like for the API Gateway to authenticate using a bearer token only and not require a cookie.

I have my solution working and have been so far testing form postman. In postman I have the bearer token but cannot find a way to access without the cookie.
My application presently runs via aws api gateway and an azure app service with azure active directory. The aws api gateway custom authoriser does not require a cookie in this case.

I have the following configuration

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /oauth2
            backend:
              serviceName: oauth2-proxy
              servicePort: 4180
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret

------
# oauth2_proxy.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: oauth2-proxy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: oauth2-proxy
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_PROVIDER
            value: azure
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_AZURE_TENANT
            value: mytennantid
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_ID
            value: my clientid
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_CLIENT_SECRET
            value: my client secret
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_COOKIE_SECRET
            value: my cookie secret
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_HTTP_ADDRESS
            value: "0.0.0.0:4180"
          - name: OAUTH2_PROXY_UPSTREAM
            value: "file:///dev/null"
        image: machinedata/oauth2_proxy:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: oauth2-proxy
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4180
          protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: oauth2-proxy
  name: oauth2-proxy
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 4180
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 4180
  selector:
    app: oauth2-proxy 
-----
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "https://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "https://$host/oauth2/start?rd=$escaped_request_uri"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - mydomain.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: mayapp
          servicePort: 80
```

I would like to change this configuration so a cookie is no longer required. If this is not possible is there another way to achieve the same outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the oauth part on kubernetes and make API Gateway validate the requests, it has the ability to do exactly what you need. You can secure your kubernetes to only accept requests from the API Gateway, so you don't need to protect your endpoint from other calls.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify authentication between AWS API Gateway and Azure Kubernetes would use IP whitelist or certificate to authenticate. What type of authentication do you recommend?

Comment: you cant really use certificate if you are talking about azure resources, if you want to implement it on nginx that might be an options, but I'd go for ip whitelisting, probably. another option (if aws api gateway can do that) is peer your azure vnet and aws vpc and send traffic internally, that way its 101% secure

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. I will look into using vnet & vpc. Another option i am looking at is Kong.